# Error:Cast to Number failed for value "undefined58" (type string) at path "TimePeriod"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to add taxes to a user using 3 parameters of User, original, and percent.
The schemas are defined below as well as the calling of the function

```
const usertaxschema = require('./schemas/usertaxschema')
const maintaxschema = require('./schemas/maintaxschema')
  const taxedamount = ((percent/100)*original).toFixed(0)
  const data = await usertaxschema.findOne({User:User})
  if(!data) {
    const newSchema = new usertaxschema({
      User:User,
      TaxesPaidInTotal:0,
      TakesPaidThisPeriod:0,
      })
      await newSchema.save().catch((err) => console.log(err))
      return 0
  }
  const chubster = await maintaxschema.findOne({Taxes:'Main'})
  chubster.TotalTaxesPaid +=taxedamount
chubster.taxesavailable += taxedamount
data.TotalTaxesPaid +=taxedamount
data.TimePeriod += taxedamount
await chubster.save()
await data.save()
return taxedamount
}
```

UserTaxSchema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const usertaxschema = mongoose.Schema({
    User:String,
    TaxesPaidInTotal:Number,
    TimePeriod:Number,
    })
module.exports = mongoose.model('usertaxes', usertaxschema, 'usertaxes')
```

MainTaxSchema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const maintaxschema = mongoose.Schema({
    Taxes:String, //Main etc
    TotalTaxesAllTime:Number,
    TaxesCollectedThisPeriod:Number,
    TaxesInBalance:Number,
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('maintaxes', maintaxschema, 'maintaxes')
```

Example of calling function

```
 const fatso = await Client.economy.taxUser(interaction.user.id, 500, 11.5)
    console.log(fatso)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Number.toFixed` returns a `String`. That's where `"58"` comes from. Then you "add" (concatenate) the `String` `"58"` to various properties that should be storing numbers, but it seems that the property `TimePeriod` is `undefined`, so then it concatenates `undefined` and `"58"` and you get the value `"undefined58"`.

You have to fix two things:

1. make sure to add numbers to numbers, instead of  adding Strings to numbers
2. check if the properties are `undefined` before you add to them

To solve #1, this line

```
const taxedamount = ((percent/100)*original).toFixed(0)
```

should use `Math.round` instead of `.toFixed`, because `Math.round` returns a number, while `.toFixed` returns a String.

```
const taxedamount = Math.round(percent / 100 * original)
```

To solve #2, you need to check for `undefined` (maybe even for `null`, if that's also a possible value) before you add values.
But are you sure you should be adding a "taxed amount" to a "time period"?

Well anyway, if that is what you want to do, and if  you want to add the amount even if the current value of the property is `undefined` (or `null`) you can default to 0 before you add

```
data.TimePeriod = (data.TimePeriod || 0) + taxedamount
```

You should do that for all properties that can contain `undefined` (or `null`) in order to not get a `NaN` (not a number) value.